# Как правильнее писать ключевые слова в загаловке страницы?

Tags: seo, html, keyword

Как правильнее записывать ключевые слова для поисковиков:

1. Вариант "торговый дом, скидки, мужская одежда"
2. Вариант "торговый,дом,скидки,мужская,одежда"
   ?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду тег <meta name="keywords" /> ??

Comment: да, именно его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевые слова должны быть наиболее релевантными Вашей странице. Если на ней содержится информация о торговом доме, то **вариант 1** является верным, ведь у Вас речь о торговом доме, а не о доме.

А вообще, можете не заморачиваться по этому поводу. Поисковики фактически не придают значения этому meta тегу.

Answer (score 0):

вот нарыл на каком то форуме. Это запись 31 Октября 2012 года

*Несколько дней назад, 6-го октября, на конференции Search Marketing Expo, представителями Yahoo было заявлено, что мета-тег keywords больше не учитывается поисковой системой Yahoo. Представителями Google подобное заявление было сделано еще в сентябре в своем блоге, вот кусочек из этого сообщения:
Наш поисковик, известный как Google.com, которым пользуются сотни миллионов людей каждый день, не учитывает мета-тег keywords. Просто этот мета-тег в настоящее время не имеет никакого значения в ранжировании.*

Comment: Google не один и это его личное дело :))). На данный момент мне больше с Яндекса заходят. А Яндекс на них поглядывает.